# Python: can't execute a php file

Tags: python, php

I have a simple hangman game written in python, I was now trying to execute some external code through my program. I set up a php script that opens/creates a txt file and writes the word down at the beginning of each game.

PHP

```
<?php
    
    $word = $argv[1];
    $file = fopen('GamesHistory.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($file, $word);
    fclose($file);
        
?>
```

Looking up on the internet i found 3 ways to achieve this:

```
subprocess.run()

subprocess.Popen()

os.system()
```

This are all the tries I made and the result

**1st Try**

```
subprocess.run('php writetofile.php ' + chosenWord)
```

Result: *code hangs indefinitely*

**2nd Try**

```
subprocess.run(['php', 'writetofile.php ', chosenWord])
```

Result: *code hangs indefinitely*

**3rd Try**

```
subprocess.run(['php', '~/hen-durance/writetofile.php ', chosenWord])
```

Result: *code hangs indefinitely*

**4th Try**

```
subprocess.run(['php', '~/hen-durance/writetofile.php ', chosenWord], shell=True)
```

Result: *code hangs indefinitely*

**5th Try**

```
subprocess.Popen(['php', '~/hen-durance/writetofile.php ', chosenWord], shell=True)
```

Result: *Code ends without error, nothing is done, the txt file is empty*

**6th Try**

```
subprocess.Popen(['php', '~/hen-durance/writetofile.php ', chosenWord], shell=True)
```

Result: *Code ends without error, nothing is done, the txt file is empty*

**7th Try**

```
subprocess.Popen(['php', '~/hen-durance/writetofile.php ', chosenWord])
```

Result: *Code ends without error, nothing is done, the txt file is empty*

**8th Try**

```
os.system('/usr/bin/php ~/hen-durance/writetofile.php' +  chosenWord)
```

Result: *Code ends without error, nothing is done, the txt file is empty*

I thought it may be that the shell command is wrong, but if i enter it manually it works like a charm. Opening python console and sending any of those commands results in the same result.

Any idea?

Comment: I really would like to know why the hassle with php code to write the word, when it can be done via python.

Comment: Version/try 2 of your call works for me. Didn't try any other.

Comment: @buran Because this is just the first step, if anything is the python file that is useless as i have to integrate it in a broader php project, but i first wanted to check if i could execute code from there. I needed something easy and easily checkable so i wrote a file-writing script

Comment: @nitrin0 i'll check again and let you know

Comment: @FabioR. for sure it's a path issue, double check it. Start by having both scripts in the same folder and go from there. If it doesn't work check if you actually are executing the php script (by echoing the parameter you receive). If, for some reason, it's empty, also check the `register_argc_argv` php.ini directive. Good luck!

Comment: @nitrin0 just tried with `subprocess.run(['/usr/bin/php', '~/hen-durance/writetofile.php ', 'banana']) ` and the result was
`Could not open input file: ~/hen-durance/writetofile.php`. I'd say we are slowly moving forward. I'll try to do some debug on this, thank you

Comment: Yeah, it's a path issue. Go to that folder (where you have the php script) and do a `pwd` :)

Comment: You need to remove the space at the end of the path in most of your examples.

Comment: @nitrin0 yes, apparently it was a path issue: if you want to use `subprocess.run()` you have to specify the FULL path of the file (starting with / ), if you want to use `os.system` you can use the path relative to your user (~/) but don't forget to format the command (i forgot to space the file and the word resulting in `php writefile.phpthewordichose` that obviously doesn't work. If you want to post an answer i'll be glad to accept it

Comment: @FabioR. no need, thank you. Glad i could help somehow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @nitrin0 I found the answer:

if you want to use `subprocess.run()` you have to specify the **FULL** path of everything (Ex. `subprocess.run(['/usr/bin/php', '/home/admin/hen-durance/writetofile.php ', word])`)

if you want to use `os.system()` you can avoid to specify the path, but remember to format the command in a proper way (Ex. `os.system('php writetofile.php ' + word)` [*notice the space before the closing quote, I didn't put that there before so my script executed `php writetofile.phpword` that obviously can't work*])